# I'd like to achieve the delete action. I can't get id

Tags: javascript, html

I'm beginner of javascript. Now, I create a application of list.
What we'd like to achieve is the delete action. I'd like to delete the one with a id. Which part is wrong?

I tried modifying the code from the commented out.

This is the code:

```html
<body>
  <h1>todo list</h1>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="item">
    <button type="button" id='click-function'>Add</button>
  </div>

  <table>
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>コメント</th><th>状態</th><th></th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="list_item">

      </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

```js
const myfunc = document.getElementById('click-function');
let count = 0;
myfunc.addEventListener('click',function(){
    let todoItems = [];
    let todoItem = document.getElementById('item').value;
    todoItems.push(todoItem);
    todoItems.forEach((element,index,array) => {
        const btn_1 = document.createElement('button');
        const btn_2 = document.createElement('button');
        btn_1.textContent = '作業中';
        btn_2.textContent = '消去';
        btn_2.type = 'button';
        btn_2.id = 'delete-' + count;
        const td_1 = document.createElement('td');
        const td_2 = document.createElement('td');
        const td_3 = document.createElement('td');
        const td_4 = document.createElement('td');
        const tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.id = "tr-" + count;
        td_1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(count));
        td_2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(todoItem));
        td_3.appendChild(btn_1);
        td_4.appendChild(btn_2);
        tr.appendChild(td_1);
        tr.appendChild(td_2);
        tr.appendChild(td_3);
        tr.appendChild(td_4);
        document.getElementById('list_item').appendChild(tr);
        btn_2.addEventListener('click',function(){
            const list_item = document.getElementById('list_item');
            const tr_count = document.getElementById('tr-'+count);
            if(tr_count){
                list_item.removeChild(tr);
                count--;
            }
        });
        count++;
    }) 
});
```

Comment: There's no element with the id `delete` when you try to add the event handler

Comment: Also, your page cannot have more than one element with `id="delete"`. `id` **must at all times be unique** per-document.

Comment: I fixed code but didn't work. Which part is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes at this line:

```
const click_del = document.getElementById('delete');
```

When this line is first executed, no element with that id exists. You need to defer this and adding the click listener to this element until it is created. You could put this code for creating the listener into a function and call it from the `click-function` element's click handler function.